# Safari css transition bug? Elements disappear

Tags: javascript, css, safari, bourbon, neat

I have an issue that is only appearing to me in Safari. I am developing a site that is fixed in position and is moved around with javascript, so you can't scroll it yourself its like a fake scroll.

Some "panels" of this system are dark and some are light so a class is appended on each panel switch to dictate whether elements should be black or white.

After load and using the site a bit, the elements that transition with the new class being added, start to disappear and flickr

I'm not sure what code snippets would help but for example this is the scss that I am putting in (Im using bourbon and neat)

```
.paginate {
    a {
        background-color:white;
        @include transition(opacity .2s, background-color .2s);
    }
}

.dark {
    .paginate a {
        background-color:black;
    }
}
```

The development site can be found here http://dev.shewasonly.co.uk/ba-wp/

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: I should add that im using Safari 7.1.3, but have noticed the bug on later versions as well